# Getting Error while running "Alter table <TableName> not logged initially" through Java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, database-administration

There are millions of records in table which I need to delete but I need to log off the transaction logs for that I use Alter Table  not logged initially but it is throwing error and makes the table inaccessible. There is no partition in table but table contain Index and Sequences. Also autocommit is off.
**Error : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68, DRIVER=3.65.77**

Getting the above error only when running through java, not getting any error if running from client.
Need to know in which all cases and scenarios the query can fail or what need make ensure before running this query. How to handle this scenario in code.

Comment: Have you tried to look up the SQLCODE value in the manual?

Comment: It indicates the deadlock scenario, any previous transaction may be open. 1.) However can you tell me is there any query to check through code whether the table is ready for exclusive lock then by seeing the output of that I will execute this query. 2.) Or any Query which will forcefully free the table and remove all the locks then I will execute the Query.

Answer (score 1):

When asking for help with Db2, always put into your question the Db2-server *version* and platform (Z/OS, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows) because the answers can depend on those facts.

The sqlcode -911 with sqlerrmc 68 is a lock-timeout. This is not a deadlock. Your job
might not be the only job that is concurrently accessing the table. Monitoring functions and administrative views let you see which locks exist at any moment in time (e.g. SNAPLOCK and SNAP_GET_LOCK table function and many others).

Refer to the Db2 Knowledge Centre for details of the suggestions below, to educate yourself.

Putting the table into not-logged-initially for your transaction is high risk, especially if you are a novice, because if your transaction fails then you can lose the entire table.

If you persist with that approach, take precautions and rehearse point in time recovery in case your actions cause damage. Verify your backups and recovery steps carefully.

With autocommit disabled, one can lock a table in exclusive mode, but this can cause a service-outage on production if the target table is a hot table. One can also force off applications that are holding locks if you have the relevant rights.

If there are any other runnning jobs (i.e. not your own code) accessing the table while you try to alter that table when the -911 is almost inevitable. Your approach may be unwise.

Bulk delete can be achieved by other means, it depends on what you wish to trade-off.
This is a frequently asked question. It's not RDBMS specific either.
Consider doing more research, as this is a widely discussed topic.

Alternative approaches for bulk delete include these:

- batching the logged deletes, commit once per batch, adjustable batch size
  ( to ensure you avoid a -964 transaction-log-full situation).
  This requires programming a loop, and you should condsider 'set current timeout not wait'
  along with retrying automatically later any failed batches (e.g batches that failed
  due to locks). This approach yields a
  slow and gradual removal of rows, but increases concurrency. You are trading 
  a long slow execution for minimal impact on other running jobs.
- Create an identical shadow table, into which you insert only the rows that you 
  wish to keep. Then use truncate table ... immediate on the target table
  (this is an unlogged action)
  and finally restore the preserved-rows from the shadow-table into the target-table.
  A less safe variation of this is to export only the rows you want to keep and then
  import-replace
- depending on Db2-licence and frequency of purge, migrating the data (or some of the data) into a range  partitioned table, and using detach may be the better long term solution

Refer to the on-line Db2 Knowledge Center for details of the above suggestions.